# TableView doesn't show anything after I add object to observableList

Tags: java, javafx

i try to add row to the tableview that i've created but the tableView keeps empty while the object is created successfully (i printed out the object and see the data are correct) how can I solve this problem?

```
public class FirstFinalRep {

private final String fN;
private final Double bE;
private final Double aE;
private final Double dE;
private final Double bV;
private final Double aV;
private final Double dV;


public FirstFinalRep(String fN, double bE, double aE, double dE,
                     double bV, double aV, double dV) {
    this.fileName = fN;
    this.bEntropy = bE;
    this.aEntropy = aE;
    this.dEntropy = dE;
    this.bVol = bV;
    this.aVol = aV;
    this.dVol = dV;
}
```

and my controller class is:

```
public class Controller {

@FXML
private TableView<FirstFinalRep> fFinalRepTable;
@FXML
private TableColumn<FirstFinalRep, String> fNameCol;
@FXML
private TableColumn<FirstFinalRep, Double> eBefCol;
@FXML
private TableColumn<FirstFinalRep, Double> eAfCol;
@FXML
private TableColumn<FirstFinalRep, Double> eDiCol;
@FXML
private TableColumn<FirstFinalRep, Double> vBefCol;
@FXML
private TableColumn<FirstFinalRep, Double> vAfCol;
@FXML
private TableColumn<FirstFinalRep, Double> vDifCol;

private List<FirstFinalRep> listFirstFinalLog= new ArrayList();
public static ObservableList<FirstFinalRep> observableFinalLogs;

public void initialize() {
    fNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<FirstFinalRep, String>("fName"));
    eBefCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<FirstFinalRep, Double>("bE"));
    eAfCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<FirstFinalRep, Double>("aE"));
    eDiCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<FirstFinalRep, Double>("dE"));
    vBefCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<FirstFinalRep, Double>("bV"));
    vAfCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<FirstFinalRep, Double>("aV"));
    vDifCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<FirstFinalRep, Double>("dV"));

    observableFinalLogs = FXCollections.observableArrayList(this.listFirstFinalLog);
    fFinalRepTable.setItems(this.observableFinalLogs);
}


public void startAnalysis() throws Exception {

    FirstFinalRep firstFinalRep = new FirstFinalRep("TA",1,2,3,4,5,6);
    observableFinalLogs.add(firstFinalRep);
}
```

As you see, when I want to add an object of FirstFinalRep class to the observable list , the tableview(fFinalRepTable) doesn't have any thing(it is empty) to show and it is like the image below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQzRB.png)

Comment: Your `FirstFinalRep` class will not compile since you're not initializing all `final` fields in the constructor (assuming there is no initializer block below the constructor that you haven't posted). You do not even show the fields that ***are*** initialized. Furthermore you haven't posted any getters for the fields. Missing those is a reason `PropertyValueFactory` would fail to retrieve the property values...